# Which API permission is needed for listing plans in a Microsoft group?

Tags: c#, azure, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I'm trying to query the Microsoft Graph API to interact with plans within a group.

I'm using this method in the SDK:

```
graphClient.Groups[id.ToString()].Planner.Plans.GetAsync();
```

However, this incurs the following exception:

> Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: You do not have the required permissions to access this item.

I've used the same `GraphClient` to list the groups, and to retrieve the group whose ID is used in the above method call, which has the following permissions assigned:

- `Group.Read.All` (*Application* and *Delegated*)
- `Group.ReadWrite.All` (*Application* and *Delegated*)
- `GroupMember.Read.All` (*Application*)
- `Tasks.Read` (*Delegated*)
- `Tasks.Read.Shared` (*Delegated*)
- `Tasks.ReadWrite` (*Delegated*)
- `Tasks.ReadWrite.Shared` (*Delegated*)
- `User.Read` (*Delegated*)

To obtain a `GraphClient` I used the code found in the sample `[here][1]`. The only part I changed is to use my own `tenantId`, `clientId`, and `clientSecret`.

What extra permission is needed to list the plans within a group?

Comment: Could you what type of permissions you granted in app registration **Application** or **Delegated**?

Comment: @Sridevi I've updated the OP with those details.

Comment: What auth provider you are using to create graph client like client credentials or interactive flows? If possible, please include complete code

Comment: I used the `Authorization Code Provider` from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#authorization-code-provider

Comment: Okay you are using delegated flow like authorization code flow that works with Delegated permissions. In that case, `Tasks.Read` Delegated permission is enough to fetch plans within a group.

Comment: The error may occur if the signed-in user is not a member of your calling group. Could you confirm whether the user account you are using to sign in is a member of the calling group or not?

Comment: The 'user' is an app registration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257234/discussion-between-sridevi-and-awj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred as you missed granting `Tasks.Read.All` permission that is required to list plans within group while using client credentials flow.

I registered one Entra ID application granted same **API permissions** as you:

[image]

When I tried to list plans within the group, I got **same error** like this:

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to grant `Tasks.Read.All` permission of **Application** type by granting **admin consent** to it as below:

[image]

When I ran below code after granting required permission, I got the **response** with list of plans successfully:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var plans = await graphClient.Groups["groupId"].Planner.Plans.GetAsync();

            foreach (var plan in plans.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Plan Title: {plan.Title}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Plan ID: {plan.Id}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{exception.GetType().FullName}: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[List plans - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannergroup-list-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)